# What is the letter and what are you?

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle

> There's a letter
>   Having a quick laugh, but it can't let you do that when incomplete,
>   Then a greeting, striking an emperor,
>   And a man, a woman, a champion,
>   Finally, something light, a goddess and her realm.

Now, the letter's important indeed, but *in the end* what matters is what you are if you think this riddle is easy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The letter is

> **H**

and you are a

> **FOOL!**

Each line describes

> a series of words starting with H, where each word adds a letter to the end of the previous.

*Having a quick laugh, but it can't let you do that when incomplete*

> HA (quick laugh) -> HAL (from *2001*) -> HALF (incomplete)

*Then a greeting, striking an emperor*

> HI (greeting) -> HIT (strike) -> HITO (emperors of Japan)

*And a man, a woman, a champion*

> HE -> HER -> HERO

*Finally, something light, a goddess and her realm.*

> HE (helium) -> HEL (Norse goddess of...) -> HELL

Then, as the instructions suggest, what matters is

> what's at the end of each final word (hal**F**, hit**O**, her**O**, hel**L**) -> **FOOL**

Comment: Well done, I guess it wasn't *that* hard :p

Comment: *"I'm sorry Dave — I'm afraid I can't do that."*